# Java8 stream - how to get convert Set to List when .map() found a Set

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to convert the result to List for the following code:

```
List<Task> taskList = projectMap.stream().map(p -> p.getProject().getTasks()).collect(Collector.toList());
```

but the problem is **p.getProject().getTasks()** is actually a **Set**, so I got this error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Set<Task>> to List<Task>
```

So I also tried to return the result as a **Set**

```
Set<Task> taskList = (Set<Task>)projectMap.stream().map(p -> p.getProject().getTasks());
```

error

```
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3 cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

Is there anyway to convert the result to List ?

or remain the result as Set also fine, my goal is to get the list of **Task** which located in **ProjectMap > Project > Task**

Comment: For every project you will get `Set<Task>` so when you collect as list it became `List<Set<Task>>`, so flat the `Set<Task>` using flatMap. Then it will be `Stream<Task>` now you can collect as list of Task . See the solution below by @Eran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
List<Task> taskList = projectMap.stream()
                                .flatMap(p -> p.getProject().getTasks().stream())
                                .collect(Collector.toList());
```